# HTML/JS/CSS syntax highlighter that supports LLVM

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntax-highlighting, google-code-prettify

I'm currently using [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) for syntax highlighting. It doesn't seem to support LLVM. Here's what it looks like when formatting LLVM:

[image]

It's pretty ugly. Are there any front-end syntax highlighters that support LLVM?

Comment: The LLVM plugin that I wrote in my answer is now a part of google-code-prettify! So it *does* support LLVM syntax now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I grabbed the patterns for LLVM assembly syntax highlighting from the [LLVM TextMate Bundle project](https://github.com/hansstimer/llvm.tmbundle) and wrote up a plugin for [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) .

```
PR['registerLangHandler'](
    PR['createSimpleLexer'](
        [
         // Whitespace
         [PR['PR_PLAIN'],       /^[\t\n\r \xA0]+/, null, '\t\n\r \xA0'],

         // A double quoted, possibly multi-line, string.
         [PR['PR_STRING'],      /^\"(?:[^\"\\]|\\[\s\S])*(?:\"|$)/, null, '"'],

         // comment.llvm
         [PR['PR_COMMENT'],       /^;[^\r\n]*/, null, ';'],
        ],
        [
         // llvm instructions
         [PR['PR_KEYWORD'],     /^\b(?:add|alloca|and|ashr|bitcast|br|call|eq|exact|extractelement|extractvalue|fadd|fcmp|fdiv|fmul|fpext|fptosi|fptoui|fptrunc|free|frem|fsub|getelementptr|icmp|inbounds|indirectbr|insertelement|insertvalue|inttoptr|invoke|load|lshr|malloc|mul|ne|nsw|nuw|oeq|oge|ogt|ole|olt|one|or|ord|phi|ptrtoint|ret|sdiv|select|sext|sge|sgt|shl|shufflevector|sitofp|sle|slt|srem|store|sub|switch|trunc|udiv|ueq|uge|uge|ugt|ugt|uitofp|ule|ule|ult|ult|une|uno|unreachable|unwind|urem|va_arg|xor|zext)\b/, null],

         // llvm keywords
         [PR['PR_KEYWORD'],     /^\b(?:addrspace|alias|align|alignstack|alwaysinline|appending|asm|blockaddress|byval|c|cc|ccc|coldcc|common|constant|datalayout|declare|default|define|deplibs|dllexport|dllimport|except|extern_weak|external|fastcc|gc|global|hidden|inlinehint|inreg|internal|linkonce|linkonce_odr|metadata|module|naked|nest|noalias|nocapture|noimplicitfloat|noinline|noredzone|noreturn|nounwind|optsize|private|protected|ptx_device|ptx_kernel|readnone|readonly|section|sideeffect|signext|sret|ssp|sspreq|tail|target|thread_local|to|triple|uwtable|volatile|weak|weak_odr|x86_fastcallcc|x86_stdcallcc|zeroext)\b/, null],

         // variable.llvm
         [PR['PR_TYPE'],       /^\s(?:[%@][-a-zA-Z$._][-a-zA-Z$._0-9]*)/],

         // variable.language.llvm
         [PR['PR_TYPE'],       /^\s(?:[%]\d+)/],

         // storage.type.language.llvm
         [PR['PR_PLAIN'],       /^\b(?:i\d+\**)/],

         // variable.metadata.llvm
         [PR['PR_PLAIN'],       /^(!\d+)/],

         // constant.numeric.float.llvm
         [PR['PR_LITERAL'],       /^\b\d+\.\d+\b/],

         // constant.numeric.integer.llvm
         [PR['PR_LITERAL'],       /^\b(?:\d+|0(?:x|X)[a-fA-F0-9]+)\b/],
        ]),
    ['llvm', 'll']);
```

Here are the links to a [demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eaPg6/3/) and a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/2850418) with a demo page and README.

Comment: I took a shot at the transplant: http://jsfiddle.net/eaPg6/ - I'm no LLVM expert, can you try it out with some actual LLVM code?

Comment: It looks awesome. I put it up on github as a gist: https://gist.github.com/2848530 - can you include it (or copy to your own gist, or just the jsfiddle) in the answer, and ill award you the bounty?

Comment: Whoot! What the **** is this lol! My human eyes got burned while reading this syntax :-). Nice job you did on the plugin!

Comment: @RobAngelier, that syntax is my fault.  Sorry about your goggles.  It's a compact way of specifying almost-regular grammars for lexers.

Comment: @NikhilDabas, I'd like to include the LLVM plugin in Google Prettify.  Are you ok with releasing it under the Apache 2.0 license and with me putting it in code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify as an official language extension?

Comment: @MikeSamuel replying to your comment on my gist!

Answer (score 1):

Pyments has support for LLVM. It is based on a python backend and the user can choose between styles.

Output modes:

- HTML
- ANSI sequences (console output)
- LaTeX combined with the package [minted](http://code.google.com/p/minted/)
- RTF

http://pygments.org/demo/45402/

Comment: But you need a server backend for pygments right? I needed a purely frontend (JS) approach

Answer (score 0):

Considering LLVM is a rather obscure programming language, it's doubtful you'll find a syntax highlighter specifically designed for it. However, that doesn't mean you can't cheat a little, and make something work. I'd recommend using SyntaxHighlighter. http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter

Though it does not natively support LLVM, it provides many built-in brushes for various other programming languages. I would try it out, and try applying different brushes (syntax highlighters) to your LLVM code. Some will match quite well, while others will appear pretty bland, like in the example you demonstrated.

If you look [here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/brushes/), you'll also see that many unofficial brushes exist as well. That is a benefit to using SyntaxHighlighter--if a brush for LLVM is ever designed (or if you decide to design it yourself) it'll be simple to implement.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you'r a linux guy, since you use Python i suppose you do. Emacs and Vim seem to support LLVM syntax highlighting. See http://llvm.org/docs/GettingStarted.html.
If you don't want to use these perhaps you can use the syntax files (with some fiddling) that are provided in other IDE's or Editors.
Googled it up so can't help you any further.
Success on your quest if this is't enough.